# Laplacian eigenfunction $L^p$ norms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory

Suppose I have a compact surface (possibly with boundary), and consider the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian, normalized so that their $L^2$ norms are $1.$ Is there some general result or conjecture on how the $L^p$ norm of $f_\lambda$ (where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue) behaves as function of $\lambda?$ Presumably this depends on the geometry of the surface (and, of course, nothing about this question is special to two dimensions, except that this case might be easier).

Comment: Search for Sogge's results on $L^p$ bounds. I believe this is an active area of study, especially when one restricts to manifolds with interesting geometric properties.

Comment: I haven't read this paper myself, but I believe the work of Sogge (J. Funct. Analysis 1988) may have results of the kind you want?

Comment: For "interesting" cases, much better bounds are known (and expected) than the general theory by Sogge. See for example the result of Iwaniec-Sarnak and all the recent work on Berry's random wave model.

Comment: @Asaf Any particular paper you recommend (on the Berry random wave thing)?

Comment: This http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.3420v1.pdf very nice survey article of Zelditch contains quite a bit of discussion about this very topic, including an overview of some of the work of Sogge.

Comment: @IgorRivin , I would try Hejhal-Rackner - "On the Topography
of Maass Waveforms for PSL(2, Z)". There are also some surveys by Peter around Quantum Chaos and spectra of surfaces, I would look there also. There is also some recent work by Templier if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out already by the comments, Sogge has indeed made a lot of contributions in this area.
Consider a 2-dimensional compact Riemannian manifold without boundary, then the $L^2$ normalized eigenfunction of Laplacian  $e_{\lambda}$ which sastisfy
$$
-\Delta e_{\lambda}=\lambda^2e_{\lambda}
$$
has the following estimate
$$
\|e_{\lambda}\|_{L^p}\leq C\lambda^{\sigma(p)},~~\lambda\ge 1,
$$
here $\sigma(p)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p})$, if $2\leq p\leq 6$, and $\sigma(p)=2(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p})-1$, if $6\leq p\leq \infty$. For dimension $n>2$, there are similar results.

However, for manifold with boundary, the problem becomes more difficult, for dimension 2, see also the Acta paper by Smith and Sogge http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605682.pdf.

It's also interesting to improve the bound above. The above estimates is sharp in general. The $L^{\infty}$ norm is saturated by the Zonal function (which is concentrated near the pole) on the round sphere. For lower $p$(below the critical point, which is 6 here), it's saturated by the highest weight hamonics (which is concentrated near the equator ). However, for manifold with nonpositive curvature, on can get some improvement($\log \lambda$), and for flat torus $\mathbb{T}^n$, one can get a further improvement ($\lambda^{\epsilon(n)})$.